# Ruby on Rails in Cloud9 doesn't recognize jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I have no idea why Ruby on Rails in Cloud 9 framework
doesn't recognize javascript applications. 
I have taken Ruby on Rails course via Udemy, and here is correct 
[repo file](https://github.com/udemyrailscourse/finance-tracker)
from Udemy teacher, and when I copy this code into Cloud 9 framework. In this file: /app/assets/javascripts/*application.js* there is a code block like this:

```
var hide_spinner = function(){
  $('#spinner').hide();
}
```

and within '$' sign is showing following error: `$ is not defined; please fix or add /* global $ */`. It's same with other files who end with .js in javascripts folder.

I have installed all gems and in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
// require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Sorry for my English :)
Please help!

Thank you! ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VarName is not defined, please fix or add /\*global VarName\*/ Cloud9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270011/varname-is-not-defined-please-fix-or-add-global-varname-cloud9)

Comment: It didn't helped :(

Answer (score 1):

Sinmply add this:

`/* global $ */`

to the top of your script

and `$ is not defined; please fix or add /* global $ */` will stop showing up!

Hope this helps, it worked for me!